# Magento Checkout Success Error

Tags: magento, paypal

After placing the order through paypal direct method,checkout success page shows the error http://pastebin.com/RZDM0kEh.
Order is displaying in backend.Catalog search type is like.Magento 1.6.1.0.

Any help?

Comment: Any background on this? What modifications have you made, what contributions installed, was it working before etc.

Comment: No modules installed.Changed catalog search from 'combine(fulltext & like)' to 'Like'.

Comment: Yes I rebuilt index several times.Still no luck

Comment: can you please post a link to your website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with local.xml file.

I have used `<update handle>` of `<catalogsearch_result_index>` page layout in `<checkout_onepage_success>` that never exists.